# Sass-loader requires node-sass >=4 even if that exist

Tags: node.js, angular, sass

I executed a update to angular 6. And during ng serve -o I receive error that sass-loader expect node-sass. 
After run ng serve -o I receive:

```
ERROR in ./src/sass/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/sass/styles.scss)
    Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
ERROR in x.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
ERROR in x.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (loader.js:31:19)
ERROR in .x.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
```

Obvisously I check everything (in my opinion) and I don't have idea what's going on.

Package.Json:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
"@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "6.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.106",
"codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-html-detailed-reporter": "^1.1.21",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
"karma-teamcity-reporter": "^1.1.0",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"node-sass": "^4.9.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
"ts-node": "~4.1.0",
"tslint": "~5.9.1",
"typescript": "2.7.2"
}
```

dir -l node_modules says:

```
...
05/07/2018  08:53 AM    <DIR>          node-sass
...
05/07/2018  08:53 AM    <DIR>          sass-loader
...
```

I executed:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

and secod approach:
I removed local node-module together with %User%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache. then I removed lock file and execuded npm

```
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

But still no success.

What do I miss ?

Comment: `sass-loader` is a dependency of angular so there is no need to specify it in the package.json. Try removing `node-sass` and `sass-loader` from the json, clear everything, install and build.

Comment: Having the same problem using `node 10.0.0` ... I now downgraded to `node 9.11.1` again and now it works ... not sure what the reason might be ....

Comment: Had the same problem. I can see you've done a rebuild already, but try a rebuild of everything: `npm rebuild --force`. That fixed it for me.

Comment: @Sebastian Hildebrandt 
I am thinking to downgrade to node 9.11 from Node 10. After that do I have to install any other modules? After upgrading to Window 10 my application stopped working and am getting the same error (Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. )

After installing this am getting the error to install Python 2 and set the PATH. I have Python 3.x installed. Now do I have to downgrade to Python 2?

My setup: Angular CLI: 6.2.1 / Node: 10.0.0 / OS: win32 x64

Answer (score 38):

```
npm rebuild --force
```

aslo helps

Comment: A little explanation of what the command does would be appreciated

Comment: Doing this resolved my issue by updating the existing: `"node-sass": "^4.6.0"` to this: `"node-sass": "^4.12.0"`. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 11):

I fixed it with

```
npm install node-sass
```

inside the project folder, and for the project, because installing it globally (with the `-g` option) didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 10):

I had same issue which I fixed using following steps:

1. Delete `package-lock.json` file.
2. Go to `node_module` folder and run `rm -rf node_modules`.
3. Run `npm install`

The `package-lock.json` file will auto-update with the new dependencies version.

hope it helps.

Comment: Did not work for me. But DarkNeuron's tip worked for me.

Comment: This problem occurred for me with an absolutely clean install on a CI server.

Comment: Might need 'npm rebuild node-sass' as step #4. Removing package-lock.json and node_modules results in pulling a new version of node-sass. However, this new version sometimes fails to build vendor.js when doing a plain 'npm install'. 'npm rebuild node-sass' builds vendor.js. No need to rebuild everything.

Comment: I got "'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: I don't have a node-module folder, just node_modules with an "s" at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue using below steps:

1. Open `package.json`
2. Add which version you want to install of `node-sass`, for example `"node-sass": "^4.12.0"`
3. Run the installation command in command line interface (CLI): `npm install node-sass`
4. The issue will get resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Simply run this code...

```
npm install --save node-sass
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue run this command

`npm install --unsafe-perm`

Answer (score 0):

Following steps solved this issue

1. Delete `node-saas` folder in `\Users\<user_id>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`
2. Delete `node-saas` folder in `<application_folder>/node_modules`
3. Run `npm install` from `<application_folder>`

Answer (score 0):

It could probably be a version mismatch. To install the working node-sass version, you can use

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.0
```

And you can **choose your version number** based on the following table, and the node version you have installed, which you can check by `node --version`

[image: node-sass compatibility table]

You can find full info [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)

This has solved my issue

Answer (score -1):

You can follow these steps:

First of all Delete `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules`.
and then Run `npm install`
The package-lock.json file will auto-update with the new dependencies version.