# Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version

Tags: npm

Can you help me? I got this error when I hit ng s

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (E:\Ibtikar\shop\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (E:\Ibtikar\shop\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
ERROR in ./src/app/detail-view/detail-view.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (E:\Ibtikar\shop\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
ERROR in ./src/app/footer/footer.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (E:\Ibtikar\shop\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
ERROR in ./src/app/products/products.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (E:\Ibtikar\shop\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
ERROR in ./src/app/slider/slider.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (E:\Ibtikar\shop\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
ERROR in ./src/app/header/header.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.
    at Object.sassLoader (E:\Ibtikar\shop\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:31:19)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to upgrade to version 4 or higher?

Comment: `npm i node-sass`

Comment: the same problem it did't work

Comment: Please remove `angular` and `angular6` tags, they are not related at all. `npm` tag would fit perfectly here.

Answer (score 26):

You need to run `npm rebuild` (or `npm rb`) in your project folder.

> This command runs the npm build command on the matched folders. This is useful when you install a new version of node, and must recompile all your C++ addons with the new binary.

[Source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rebuild)

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

Comment: This literally worked at the first attempt! Thanks a ton for sharing!

Comment: is it possible do not use node sass but using dart sass? the node-sass was not recommand. @giveJob

Answer (score 6):

`npm rebuild node-sass --force` : should work

Answer (score 4):

`npm rebuild --force` - this will rebuild all packages. Only this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try rebuilding `node-sass` using `npm rebuild node-sass` and check if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

## working solution

Step 1 `rm -rf node_modules` it removes the directory recursively (the existing node modules, takes a min or two)

Step 2 `npm install` this will work for sure, i did try and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue even after upgrading node-saas to version above 4 then follow below thread

[Sass-loader requires node-sass >=4 even if that exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210311/sass-loader-requires-node-sass-4-even-if-that-exist/56680092#56680092)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing webpack solved the issue for me.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

or, you can try :

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Answer (score 0):

check for the supported version. As on date I had node 12.x installed on my machine and spent an hour running `npm install node-sass` and `npm rebuild node-sass` with `--force` and `--save-dev` hints.

Nothing worked until I uninstalled the node 12.x and installed node 10.x. So if you're hitting the same problem and could not get it to work, try following

- Check if your Node version (Run `node -v`) if it's higher than 10.x
- Uninstall the Node 12.x from your machine
- Download and Install Node 10.x
- Restart the console/editor (not required for all and may work without this step)