# Why I can't run “npm run sass”?

Tags: npm

```
"ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
```

Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version."

Comment: If you have a `package.json` and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`, please, add the parts regarding `sass-loader` and its dependencies (to see if there is any problem there).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module build failed: Error: \`sass-loader\` requires \`node-sass\` >=4. Please install a compatible version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499253/module-build-failed-error-sass-loader-requires-node-sass-4-please-insta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install node-sass by running  `npm i node-sass`  in your terminal. You should be able to run the other after doing that.